# Table view controller not showing data when assigned to contentViewController property in popup

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a popover that appears from a button, with a table view controller and table view inside it. I have created a separate data source for the table view. Everything is hooked up in the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard connections]

I am keeping a reference to the table view controller in the app's main view controller (to do work after the popover is dismissed). I want to persist the selections in the table view inside the popover. Here's my -prepareForSegue:sender: method in the main view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Popover"]) {
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popover = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        popover.popoverController.delegate = self;
        popover.popoverController.contentViewController = (AJFTableViewController *)self.filterTableViewController;
    }
}
```

My problem is this: when I assign the popover's contentViewController to the table view controller that the app's main view controller has a reference to (last line of the method above), no data appears in the table view. I have confirmed that the data source is being created, and even tried manually calling reloadData on the tableView at the end of that method, but still nothing appears.

If I comment out the last line (that assigns the popover contentViewController to the table view controller property), I see data in the table view. However, a new table view controller is created each time the popover appears, which is not what I want.

How do I correctly assign the popover's contentViewController to the table view controller I'm holding on to in the app's main view controller, so that it displays data when the popup appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use a segue to do this, since segues always instantiate new controllers. If you want to reuse the same instance of the content controller, then you need to present it in code something like this,

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) AJFTableViewController *filterTableViewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popController;
@end

@implementation ViewController


- (IBAction)showPopover:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (! self.filterTableViewController) {
        self.filterTableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Table"];
    }
    self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.filterTableViewController];
    self.popController.delegate = self;
    [self.popController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that seques always instantiate new controllers.